# Scrapy: how can I extract text with hyperlink together

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm crawling a professor's [webpage](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/esps/people/academic-staff-permanent/kristin-bakke).

Under her research description, there are two hyperlinks, which are " TEDx UCL" and "here".

I use xpath like `'//div[@class="group"]//p/text()'`
to get the first 3 paragraphs.

And `'//div[@class="group"]/text()'` to get the last paragraph with some newlines. But these can be cleaned easily.

The problem is the last paragraph contains only text. The hyperlinks are lost. Though I can extract them separately, it is tedious to put them back to their corresponding position.

How can I get all the text and keep the hyperlinks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text).

```
sample = response.xpath("//div[@class="group"]//p/text()")
converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
converter.ignore_links = True
converter.handle(sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'//div[@class="group"]/p//text()[normalize-space(.)]'
```